# Random math problem related to clock time

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a likely strange math problem I came up with randomly and I was curious of the answer.

Say you want to multiply the last two digits of a time on a digital clock by some number for each of them and add them together to reach the hour number, excluding :00 (first minute of an hour). You know what the hour is, so you can base your equations around that. What I want to know is: for all combinations of hour/minute except when the minute is 0, what is the lowest value you need to be able to always reach the hour, assuming a 12-hour clock? An example of this for say, 1:23, would be if you took the last two digits of the time (2 and 3) and multiplied them each by a sperate factor (or the same one, if desired) to so that the sum of those products is equal to 1 (the hour). So, (2*0.5 = 1) + (3*0 = 0) = 1, which is the hour. We are trying to minimize the largest factor used for any of the possible times.

I think for this case it cannot be less than 12, since for :01 and :10 you would need to multiply the singular 1 by 12 to reach 12.
Also I do not know much about maths and if this would even be difficult to solve. I feel like the answer for this case is just 12, but what about for other cases such as the minute range being :11 to :59 or some arbitrary range? Is there a way to calculate the lowest factor you can use to reach the hour consistently? What about for 24-hour clocks?

If this is a poor question it can just be removed, also I would like some title ideas since I have no idea what to title this, I just thought of it randomly. I would also like to know if this falls under some category of math so I know what to tag it as.

Comment: For each combination of hour and minutes, there are two multipliers, one for the tens digit and one for the units digit. What do you want to minimise? Their sum? Their product? Their larger value?

Comment: @peterwhy im trying to minimise the largest factor that is needed for the individual minutes to be multiplied by so that when the products are added together, the sum is equivalent to the hours value

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. E.g., what solutions are possible if the clock displays $1:23$. It would be helpful if you could write down some examples to make it clearer what you actually mean.  (And please, do, because this is the kind of problem that I love to think about while staring at the timers on the machines in the gym $\ddot{\smile}$).

Comment: @robarthan alright, will do haha
Btw for 1:23 some examples would be 2*0.5 (1) and 3*0 (0), because 1+0 = 1, which is the hour in this timestamp

Comment: Thanks. Your comment and edit make it clear that you aren't restricting to whole number multiples, which was the cause of my confusion about your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let the hour be $h$, and the minute be $10m_1 + m_0$.

Let $a$ and $b$ be the two multipliers to be determined, for the given combination of hour and minute. Then $a$ and $b$ should satisfy

$$\begin{align*}
h &= am_1 + bm_0\\
&\le \max(a,b)m_1 + \max(a,b)m_0\\
\max(a,b) &\ge \frac{h}{m_1+m_0}
\end{align*}$$

For any combination of hour and minute, equality can always be achieved by choosing $a = b = \max(a,b)$.

Then $\max(a,b)$ is largest when $h$ is the largest and $m_1+m_0$ is the smallest, i.e. at $12:01$ or $12:10$ as in your question.

The corresponding $\max(a,b)$ is $\frac{12}{0+1} = 12$. This is the lowest value you need to be able to always reach the hour.

Comment: Oh wow, that is an intuitive solution. I like intuitive maths things becuase they are always fun